# "Stretching" subtitles with command line tool

Tags: video, multimedia, video-subtitles

I got a video file with a duartion of e.g. 30 mins and a subtitle file that belongs to this video. But the subtitle file only lasts 25 minutes.

Now I'm searching for a way to achieve the following: I want to "stretch" those subtitles so that they also last 30 mins with a command line tool (to do this automatized in a little program). So the times when a caption is shown needs to be "scaled". For example, if a caption is shown from `0` to  `10` seconds, it should be corrected to `0` to `10*30/25=12` seconds.

This is possible with Gnome Subtitles by `sync --> correct` and changing the end time, but this program only has a GUI.

So, is there a tool that has a CLI to archieve this?